# Is it possible to capture DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE in ODP.Managed net 12 c

Tags: plsql, .net-4.5, odp.net-managed

Need to capture  a procedure's DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE which is executed within a loop reading a cursor. Is this possible wit new ODP.Net Managed assembly ?

Apologize, I did not mention earliear, the Net call is a synchronous call. Will DBMS_OUTPUT be captured by OracleInfoMessageEventHandler ?

Answer (score 1):

If the ODP.Net is running with the **same Oracle session** as the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE calls then it can call DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE (or GET_LINES) to retrieve the messages from the buffer.  Otherwise no.